# Making two filter table dropdowns work at same time

Tags: javascript, filter, html-table, dropdown

I'm trying to make the location filter dropdown and category dropdown work at the same time so that table values show up according to both location and category, but the displayDate function for this isn't working.  Here's the website: https://opportunities.sarahlim3.repl.co/discover.html
Here's the code for the page:

```
<div class="search-box">
  <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" id="searchList" onkeyup="searchFunction()" placeholder="Search by name..."> <a class="search-btn" href="#">
<i class="fas fa-search"></i>
  </a>
</div>
      
    <select id="mylist" class='form-control'>
          <option value="">Filter by location</option>
    
     <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
                <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
    </select> 
    
    
    
    
<select id="categorylist" class='form-control'>
    <option value="">Filter by category</option>

 <option value="Computer Science">Computer Science</option>
            <option value="Science">Science</option>
            <option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>
           <option value="Business/Marketing">Business/Marketing</option>
            <option value="Music">Music</option>
            <option value="Art">Art</option>
           <option value="All STEM fields">All STEM fields</option>
</select> 
<button onclick="displayDate()">Submit</button>

    <table id="show" style="padding:30px; width:90%;" class="internshipInfo">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Internship name</th>
           <th>Internship location</th>
           <th>Internship category</th>
           <th>Internship link</th>
  <th>Internship deadline</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
     </table>
     
<script>
function searchFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("searchList");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("show");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
    
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      
    }
  }
}
</script>


<script>
function displayDate() {
  var input, input2 filter, filter2, table, tr, td, i, test;
  input = document.getElementById("mylist");
  input2 = document.getElementById("categorylist");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  filter2 = input2.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("show");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    test = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2]
    if (td) {
      if (td.toUpperCase() === filter && test.toUpperCase() === filter2) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
         
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      
      }
      
    }       
  }


}
</script>
```

Comment: WElcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for posting your code - please identify what function is failing, what the expected result is, how to reproduce, etc

Comment: it is very confusing. is that you have no idea which lines are causing you trouble in the 250 lines here? otherwise you would ask a question with just the useful parts and not the whole html page